# remove html tag using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I have an html element on my website that is being put there beyond my control and I need to remove it using javascript/jquery. The HTML tag is consistent and on every page, it looks like this:

```
<img src="https://myimage.com/myimage.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;border:none;">
```

how do I remove it? The image has no ID. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: are there other image tags on your page?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `->` http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ `<-`

Comment: Doesn't the parent have an ID you can use?

Comment: you don't need an Id to select an element.

Comment: Don't remove copyright...

Answer (score 4):

You can remove it like this:

```
jQuery("img[src='https://myimage.com/myimage.jpg']").remove();
```

Be sure that that code is in a `script` tag *below* the relevant image in the markup of the page. If the image is being added dynamically after the page markup has been parsed, you may have to be more crafty:

```
(function() {
    function removeImage() {
        var img = jQuery("img[src='https://myimage.com/myimage.jpg']");
        if (img.length) {
            // It's there now, remove it
            img.remove();
        }
        else {
            // Not there yet, check again in a quarter of a second
            setTimeout(removeImage, 250);
        }
    }
    removeImage(); // Start the process
})();
```

---

Note: You're removing an *element*, not a *tag*. Tags are markup (text). Elements are the result of tags being parsed and created by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$("img[src='https://myimage.com/myimage.jpg']").remove();
```

That will hide that image

Comment: How is this any different than TJ's answer?

Comment: didnt realize he meant actual removal, fixed

Comment: it's not , TJ posted it probably 30 seconds before me

Comment: 99 seconds to be exact `;)`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
$("img[src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png']").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bowenac/GD64n/

Mind explaining what the image is or post a live link? This will remove it from displaying but will not fix the source of the problem if this is some kind of hack placing this code into your files...

Comment: I hope he doesn't have any other images on the page :/

Comment: `$("body").empty()` would be just as effective

Comment: I was in the middle of editing it using an actual image with jsfiddle when I came back everyone had already posted what I was going to post so...

Comment: All in all sounds like you had good intentions but others were just plain faster on the trigger. Probably better if you deleted your answer instead of losing the rep.

Comment: *"I was in the middle of editing"* Don't post poor answers and then edit. Post an answer you'd be happy with having there for hours if (say) your internet connection went down immediately after you posted. Posting something not useful and then editing is, well, not useful.

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery, plain JS:

```
var img = document.querySelector('img[src="https://myimage.com/myimage.jpg"]');
if (img) {
    img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
}
```